# Ionic 2 Changing between tab pages

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to change between two tab pages that have different tabs. Basically what I want is to have a two tab page at the bottom when the app is first opened, but when the user logs in, then change to a four page tab system. I am able to switch between pages, but the tabs stay. `setRoot()` doesn't work with changing the tabs at the bottom to the new tabs page and neither does `pop()` or `push()`. Is there a way to switch between the tabs pages to where they change from a two tab system to a four tab system after a button is clicked?